# Wireshark 802.11 radio information calculation

Tags: wireshark

I'm trying to figure out how some of the fields are calculated in Wireshark in the 802.11 radio information. They aren't part of the packet so I'm trying to find how to calculate them myself for an external sniffing program. Specifically given a packet I need to know what the physical type of the packet is ie b, g, or n, as well as the duration and preamble times. Any help on where I should look or documentation that covers it would be great. I've tried looking at it's github but its a bit of a maze for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Good luck with [packet-ieee80211-radio.c](https://github.com/wireshark/wireshark/blob/4988cca14da57b64a6432d237d3cc208e39e71bb/epan/dissectors/packet-ieee80211-radio.c).

These information is calculated from [802.11 radiotap header](https://ask.wireshark.org/questions/56036/80211-radiotap-header).